# Hide popups while some activity is opened in custom android app

Tags: android, hide, android-popupwindow

i want to know that is there any way by which we can disable or hide the popup when our apps is opened.No popup should be show over the screen while My App is opened.Like Facebook Messenger or Whatsapp Popup came over the screen anytime.

Thanks.